# What are some drawbacks to using CrossRider as platform for developing extensions for multiple browsers?

Tags: cross-browser, browser-extension, crossrider

I've read a lot of positive insights in using CrossRider compared to its competitors but I haven't read anything related to any of its limitations (functions, speed, integration with third party services, etc.).

Comment: CrossRider is identified (wrongly in the general case) by common anti virus vendors as malware. This means anyone trying to install your extension gets a big red "THIS IS A VIRUS" warning because some scammer at some point used crossrider for malware and made all our lives harder.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The biggest drawback of using any framework is the fact that you are bound to the limitation of that framework.

However, if you see that what you are looking to achieve is feasible using the framework (and most likely Crossrider will fit your needs) then you will find out that it is going to save you a tremendous amount of time and effort, in comparison of doing all the hard work yourself.

I would suggest that you will check their [cross-browser development framework](http://crossrider.com) and see what can be done and can't be done. And if what you are looking for can be done - obviously go for it. Instead of learning the Firefox and Chrome APIs along with C++ for IE development, you only need to be familiar with Javascript (and jQuery).

Crossrider has an online IDE which lets you dive right into the code in matter of seconds. No need to download any development SDKs (unless you really want to), and you will see your code changes take affect in real-time.

Other benefits that are worth mentioning are their publishing tools, such as direct download links, the widget generator and the dynamic Window installer that can install your extension on all browsers automatically.

(disclosure: I am one of the employees of Crossrider)

Comment: btw, you can contact crossrider's support (support@crossrider.com) and describe exactly what you want to build and what your needs are. they will help you understand if its possible or not, and if possible, what's the best way(s) to make it happen.

Answer (score 7):

A few drawbacks that I found:

In my case, the extension is not the main part of your application (I have a desktop solution that downloads and converts Flash videos to other formats, and CrossRider is used just to add Download links in pages that contain Flash videos). Let's call my application FVD (Flash Video Downloader).

Drawbacks:

1. FVD and the CrossRider code are installed as 2 separate entries in "Add Remove Programs", which is confusing to users (ideally it should be only 1 entry, FVD in my case, or at least have a way of hiding the CrossRider entry)
2. FVD can be configured (for example users don't want to have links shown on sites A and B), but passing the configuration to the CrossRider extension is not easy/straightforward (since you have only one extension for all users, you can't pass an argument to customize it based on each user's choices). You could use sockets (for example making a request from the extension to localhost:8181, and have a socket listen on port 8181 from your main application), but that just seems hackish and prone to errors.

Answer (score 0):

As of 26th of September 2016 Crossrider is no longer providing its extension development platform as per this email sent to its users:

> Dear Partners,
>
> All good things must come to an end eventually and, regretfully, so
>   does the Crossrider Extensions Development Platform.
>
> After several years of collaborating with you, we have decided to
>   terminate the service.
>
> Please be advised that termination of the service is effective
>   immediately upon publication or otherwise receipt of this notice.
>
> For your ease, Crossrider Extensions Development Platform will remain
>   available for another 30 days from 27.09.2016 for you to download your
>   project code / source code / extensions, following which your data
>   will be lost.
>
> See below an instruction note on how to download the project code from
>   our server for your easy reference; but kindly note that Crossrider is
>   not able to provide further assistance.
>
> We would like to thank you for all your support and trust throughout
>   the years and hope we can have the opportunity to collaborate again in
>   the future.
>
> Best,
>
> Crossrider Team

So I'd consider that a pretty big limitation.